# BizTalk: Caller identify authenication

Tags: authentication, ssl-certificate, biztalk, biztalk-2010

In an upcomming BizTalk 2010 project we will have a web service that clients call to submit data, and a web service that clients call to request data.  At the biztalk application level this will happen by exposing orchestrations as wcf services.

At a server level, we will have a 2 node web farm, a 2 node biztalk group and a sql cluster.  The web services will obviously be deployed on the web farm, and orchestrations, send/receive ports will run on the BizTalk group servers.

We would like to authenticate callers and map their identities to active directory accounts, so that at the orchestration level, we would have the ability to access the AD identity of the caller, and pass the account name to a stored procedure in a database.

Presumably we could handle the identity mapping via SSL certificates, but we haven't done this before.  Are there some good samples/tutorials out there?

Comment: I would look at leveraging Windows Identity Framework for doing claims based identity.  While I've never done this specifically with BizTalk, dealing with identity at that AD level is not a strong suit of BizTalk.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add an endpoint behavior to add the name from the WindowsIdentity to a WCF header? That way (at least in my situation) the identity is more easily available further down the pipeline, but is that sufficient for your "account name" purposes?

```
#region IDispatchMessageInspector Members

public object AfterReceiveRequest(
    ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,
    System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel,
    System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    if (ServiceSecurityContext.Current == null || 
        ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity == null) 
        return null;

    WindowsUserName windowsUserName = new WindowsUserName();
    request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
        windowsUserName.Name, windowsUserName.Namespace,
        ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name));
    return null;
}

public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    return;
}

#endregion
```

The same actually applies when using client certificates, but using `PrimaryIdentity` instead of `WindowsIdentity` to get the BizTalk party name. This has no direct link with active directory accounts though.